# Can not make a user model for both superuser and regular users. Django/Mysql

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

There is an auth_users table in the database which is built in. If I login any superuser then that superusers information is stored in the auth_user table. There is also another table named authorization_userprofile (authorization is the app name) which stores all the regular users information.

This is my model.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models


class UserProfileManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, phone_number, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not phone_number:
            raise ValueError('The Phone Number field must be set')
        user = self.model(phone_number=phone_number, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)  # Hash the password
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, phone_number, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        return self.create_user(phone_number, password, **extra_fields)


class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')  # Added first name field
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')  # Added last name field
    dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)  # Added Date of Birth field
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, default='')  # Added email field
    address = models.TextField(default='')  # Added address field

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # other fields if any ...

    objects = UserProfileManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'

    # Unique related name to avoid clashes with auth.User model
    groups = models.ManyToManyField('auth.Group', related_name='user_profiles', blank=True)
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField('auth.Permission', related_name='user_profiles', blank=True)

    # other fields if any ...
```

This is in my settings.py
If i have this users can login and if their is_stuff is set to true then they can login to admin panel also but if they try to update any data in admin panel then an integrity error shows up because admin_log can not get the foreign key from auth_users because that regular user is not from auth_users, it's from authrozation_userprofiles

```
#For Users
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.UserProfile'
```

Now when I have this code in settings.py. The regular users can not login but the superusrs can. And in the admin panel superusers can also change the data because now admin_data_log table is getting the foreign key from auth_users

```
#For Admins
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.user'
```

Here is my view.py if you need it

```
# views.py

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponse
from twilio.rest import Client
import random
from django.conf import settings  # Import Django settings module
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password, check_password
from .models import UserProfile  # Import your UserProfile model


def mylogin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        phone_number = request.POST.get('phone_number')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        # Retrieve user profile based on phone number
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(phone_number=phone_number).first()

        print(user_profile)  # Debug: Print user_profile to check if it's retrieved correctly

        if user_profile is not None and check_password(password, user_profile.password):
            # Password matches, log the user in
            
            
            user = authenticate(request, username=phone_number, password=password)
            print(user)


            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')  # Redirect to the home page after successful login
        else:
            # User authentication failed, show error message
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid phone number or password. Please try again.')
            return redirect('mylogin')  # Redirect back to the login page if authentication fails

    return render(request, 'login.html')


def verify_otp(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_otp = request.POST.get('otp')
        stored_otp = request.session.get('otp')
        phone_number = request.session.get('phone_number')

        if user_otp == stored_otp:
            # OTP is correct, create a user profile
            password = request.POST.get('password')

            # Hash the password
            hashed_password = make_password(password)

            # Check if a user profile with the given phone number already exists
            user_profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(
                phone_number=phone_number,
                defaults={'password': hashed_password}
            )

            # Clear the OTP data from the session
            del request.session['otp']
            del request.session['phone_number']

            messages.success(request, 'OTP verified successfully!')
            return redirect('mylogin')  # Redirect to the login page
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid OTP. Please try again.')
            return redirect('myregister')  # Redirect back to the registration page if OTP is invalid

    # Handle GET requests (if any) here
    return render(request, 'authentication/login.html')


def myregister(request):
    return render(request, 'register.html')

def send_otp(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        phone_number = request.POST.get('phone_number')
        otp = str(random.randint(1000, 9999))  # Generate a random 4-digit OTP

        # Send the OTP via Twilio
        client = Client(settings.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, settings.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)
        message = client.messages.create(
            body=f'Your OTP is: {otp}',
            from_=settings.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
            to=phone_number
        )

        # Store the OTP in session for verification
        request.session['otp'] = otp
        request.session['phone_number'] = phone_number
        print(otp)
        return HttpResponse("OTP sent successfully")


def mylogout(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')
```

Honestly I am new in Django trying to build a project. And i have been very frustrated about this issue it. It took so much of my timem and still unsolved. I have no idea where auth_users table comes from. What I want to do is all the regular user and admins are stored in the auth_users so that everyone can login.
Please suggest me ways if you have any better ideas to handle this.
Thank you.

Comment: It's over complicated) why do you need 2 models? You can leave standard Django model (you can import it by `get_user_model()`), `is_staff` attribute controls access to the Django admin. Then, you can create a separate model UserProfile with one-to-one relation to User if you need to store more information about the user.

Comment: I'd say the same as @VitaliiVolkov. You just need a `User` model and if you want to store extra data, it's good practice to setup a `Profile` model which has a `OneToOneField` to `User`. I'd also recommend django-allauth for all things user related; https://pypi.org/project/django-allauth/

Comment: @VitaliiVolkov I wanted to do the same but i don't know how to access in auth_user table. I also want to change the architecture of auth_user. I don't want any username attribute there, instead I want to use phone number as unique attribute. In the varify_otp of view.py the users are stored. Will you please provide me some code to access auth_user and how to change the architecture of that table. Thank you for your valuable comment

Comment: @markwalker_ please see my last comment. Thank you for you valuable time and comment

Comment: I'd probably suggest you start with a copy/past of the django `User` model, then add the fields you want on your user. The docs for this are here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user

Comment: @markwalker_ Can I change the identifier 'username' here and swap it with 'phonemumber' which will be my identifier?

Comment: That just needs to refer to a field that's used as the unique identifier for a user; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.USERNAME_FIELD